# Can the python csv.dictwriter handle string fields that start with a plus sign?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a csv using the python csv.dictwriter and open it with Excel 2013 so that everything is a string (left justified by default) and leave it in the *.csv format in Excel, too.

To get strings everywhere I use the QUOTE_ALL feature.  To connect with Excel, I use the default Excel dialect.  However, I get a name error when I put a string starting with a + sign into a cell, and any fields that are numeric (within the quotes).   I can get rid of the name error by inserting a blank before the plus sign,  but I really do not want the blank there.

I think that the way to get Excel to accept all this is to pass the strings with a leading equals sign before the opening double quote, ie:

="Field 1",="2",="+Third Field Here", ...

Is there any way to get the python libraries (latest 3.61 release) to accomplish something like this? I like the idea of a bulletproof library instead of rolling my own,  as I have no control over what shows up within my data fields,  but is this a covered use case for the standard library?

Comment: Does Excel or the CSV writer report that error? Have you tried a different spreadsheet program?

Comment: Then name error just shows up when the data hits excel.  As the field comes in "+XYZ", excel apparently thinks that the field is a formula, and it is probably looking for something called XYZ to add into the cell. I have had good results, not using the python library, passing the data in as ="+XYZ", which evidently assigns the entire string in quotes after the = sign to the cell instead of treating it as a formula.

Comment: Please explain _**To connect with Excel, I use the default Excel dialect.**_. What do mean with _**connect**_ and _**default Excel dialect**_.

Comment: The class I am using is the csv.DictWriter.  It writes the csv (to a file). Excel reads the csv (opens the file where the DictWriter wrote it).  The constructor of the DictWriter has an optional parameter to select a dialog.  I do not supply that parameter.  The default thus applies, which is the Excel dialect.